# Stack with global z-index?

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, z-index, flutter-web

I have a `DataTable` in which some cells have links. Ideally, I would like to fetch a preview about the link's content whenever hovering over the link, which I was able to achieve using the `Stack` widget. However, since the stacked preview is inside the `DataCell`, it seems like I'm not able to raise its "`z-index`" to be on top of the rest of the table.

[image: messed up z-index]

Is this not possible with Flutter, or is there a way around it?

The only way I imagine this working, without something to update a global `z-index`, would be for the cell to update a global state and then have the thumbnail preview appear on a `Stack` above the `DataTable` level. But I wish there was a less clunkier way to do it...

3 widgets I've tried but to no avail — they might work, I don't know —:

- `Tooltip`
- `Overlay`
- `FloatingActionButton`

My whole app is [here](https://github.com/FanaroEngineering/dogemp/), and the precise commit is [`0303732`](https://github.com/FanaroEngineering/dogemp/commit/03037321856f667d9c877ad611f98369b2f8cbf3). The relevant code is this [`ClickableLink`](https://github.com/FanaroEngineering/dogemp/blob/master/lib/widgets/clickable_link.dart) widget:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

import '../schema/links.dart';

@immutable
class ClickableLink extends StatefulWidget {
  const ClickableLink({
    Key? key,
    required this.link,
    this.linkText,
    this.color = Colors.blue,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Link link;
  final String? linkText;
  final Color color;

  @override
  State<ClickableLink> createState() => _ClickableLinkState();
}

class _ClickableLinkState extends State<ClickableLink> {
  Widget hoverWidget = const SizedBox.shrink();

  void _fetchPreview(PointerEvent pointerEvent) {
    setState(() {
      if (widget.link.host == 'online-go.com' && widget.link.prePath == 'game') {
        hoverWidget = Positioned(
          top: 25,
          child: Image.network('https://online-go.com/api/v1/games/${widget.link.id}/png'),
        );
      }
    });
  }

  void _onExit(PointerEvent pointerEvent) {
    setState(() {
      hoverWidget = const SizedBox.shrink();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
      onHover: _fetchPreview,
      onExit: _onExit,
      child: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          SelectableText.rich(
            TextSpan(
              text: widget.linkText ?? widget.link.id,
              style: TextStyle(color: widget.color),
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () async => launch(widget.link.completeLink),
            ),
          ),
          hoverWidget,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the [`Overlay`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html) widget is a better option than `Stack` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is due to the fact that your `Stack` widget, defined inside `ClickableLink`, will be at a "lower" point (inside your app widget tree) than every other `GameResultCell`.
So even the higher `z-index` will still be behind the other `GameResultCell`s.

To fix this I would reccomend changing your structure and define an higher point in your structure to show the preview.

Another way could be using a library to nest your preview inside a tooltip. Take a look at this one for example:
[`just_the_tooltip: ^0.0.11+2`](https://pub.dev/packages/just_the_tooltip). With this package, you could even use a `StatelessWidget`.

The result here is more similar to what I suppose you were expecting.

[image]

```dart
class ClickableLink extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return JustTheTooltip(
      content: Image.network(
        'https://online-go.com/api/v1/games/${widget.link.id}/png',
      ),
      child: SelectableText.rich(
        TextSpan(
          text: widget.linkText ?? widget.link.id,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: widget.color ??
                (DogempTheme.currentThemeIsLight(context)
                    ? const Color(0xff1158c7)
                    : Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.85)),
          ),
          recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
            ..onTap = () async => launch(widget.link.completeLink),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Lastly you could use a `Dialog`, but the resulting behaviour is a bit different.
Take a look at this code if you want to try:

```dart
class _ClickableLinkState extends State<ClickableLink> {
  Widget hoverWidget = const SizedBox.shrink();

  void _fetchPreview(PointerEvent pointerEvent) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return Dialog(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Image.network(
                  'https://online-go.com/api/v1/games/${widget.link.id}/png'),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 16.0,
              ),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () async => launch(widget.link.completeLink),
                  child: const Text('Go to complete link'))
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
      onHover: _fetchPreview,
      child: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          SelectableText.rich(
            TextSpan(
              text: widget.linkText ?? widget.link.id,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: widget.color ??
                    (DogempTheme.currentThemeIsLight(context)
                        ? const Color(0xff1158c7)
                        : Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.85)),
              ),
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () async => launch(widget.link.completeLink),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Damn, that `just_the_tooltip` package is impressive when examining the code behind it. And, quite frankly, it's the type of thing that should be one of the native Flutter widgets. Anyway, thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: In the `Dialog` solution, is there a way of having it appear only when the mouse is directly hovering the link? I think Flutter undestands it to be kind of another screen, so it won't know if anything is being hovered on a previous screen.

Comment: Actually in the code I wrote the dialog is shown when mouse hover the link. The point is that the dialog cover the entire screen when it gets displayed. In that moment you actually loose the hover on the link.
You could use a MouseRegion to better handle the hover, but It would be very difficult imo to replicate the tooltip result.